# How to share custom app in Rally?

Tags: rally

I created custom app for my company. How I can share this app with other departments in my company, with out copy & paste?

Can I add my custom app to the local Rally apps catalog?

I found information how to create a custom page with my app and share it, but this isn't my case.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent question.  Workspace administrators have the ability to share a custom page with the other users in the workspace right now.

The local catalog idea is an awesome one and we've discussed implementing something like that a few times.  I encourage you to vote for that idea on Rally Ideas:
http://ideas.rallydev.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?idea_id=6C33CB02-4478-45A2-9990-6F19F859D799